# Core Data - managing contexts

Tags: ios, core-data

I want you people to comment on everything I write, because I want to know whether I'm on right track. So, here it is.

1. Would you say that using multiple managed object contexts was the right way when you had app with multiple view controllers that did different tasks? I figured out that having singleton context and child context in view controllers can solve the problem when you want to save just part of context, i.e. creating small, local context and push everything on main context before saving it to store. **For example, I created some object using one VC which is part of context now, but I didn't press save new object. But then, with new object, I went to other VC and saved something else. The problem is that being part of same context, you save whole state of context. It seems in this situation that I have to separate contexts.**
2. I thought using context hierarchy would propagate changes made on one context to parent and then other child would see edited data when fetching again, but this is not the case. If I want to see the changes, I have to use `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` with `YES` as a parameter. Plus, I have to fetch again to check for new records. Is there a better solution? **For example, I loaded VC according to my settings, went to other VC, changed settings and saved it. Now when I get back, I want in viewWillAppear: to get changes and change GUI according to changes made in settings. But, the problem is that when I fetch settings, I get same data, I presume because of caching? But what's the point for parent context then in this scenario?**
3. So, is there really need for multiple contexts if you have to fetch and refresh all the time? **Similar to above, why linking context if they don't propagate changes?**
4. Reseting context - When is good time to reset context? If I use singleton context, everything is being stored in it, so after some time, it might use a lot of memory, right? So, from this point of view, do I really want to use singleton with context?**For example, I have a list of objects I present in some tableView. Since in hierarchy I hold it all the time because it's part of navigation stack, should I hold all of the objects all the time, or dispose them and get them again when I get to that VC? I mean, I can't do a lot with objects if they belong to different contexts. I'd have to get objects by their IDs to use them with context which is not connected, right?**

Comment: I think it would be helpful to understand what your needs are as well.  Even though you're asking good questions, often times a better solution may be provided if someone understands why you're looking into multiple MOC and parent/child heirarchy. Often the context is being accessed from many different VCs but you don't need multiple MOC. If you're accessing it from both the main thread/background thread simultaneously, then it's a different story (as well as if there is  a background thread that is read/writing a lot of data)

Comment: @LyricalPanda Thanks for reply. I tried to explain my dilemma and added some BOLD text. I think that sharing data between VCs is common and yet, couldn't find good tutorial or explanation. I know that Core Data is very powerful and great to work with, but I'd really like to learn some best practices for different sceanrios.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not a CoreData Expert, but I'll try tackling each. You should read this great [article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) on Core Data, namely the Parent-Child context on getting it to propagate changes up.

1) I believe it's common practice to save your context as you go - what is the use case that you want to alter data on one VC, go to the next one, alter more data and save it, but disregard the data on the previous? If you meant to simply discard changes, then `[managedObjectContext rollback]` should be what you call on canceling to reset the state of your context.

2) I'm assuming you've set your VC up in a parent-child hierarchy as described in the article - if so, then ensure you're saving the context of both the child and parent. The child pushes changes up to the parent, then saving the parent actually saves the changes in coredata. On viewWillAppear, when you poll CoreData, then the changes should be present.

3) See the awesome article linked above for saving both child and parent contexts :)

4) I haven't had to reset the context for the sake of freeing up memory. Generally from what I've seen is that people do use a singleton (then parent-child for updating data in the background) that is instantiated on appload. One of the big SO point guys can probably better describe what happens with memory, but if you're really worried you can nil out the VC's context pointer to the singleton on `ViewDidDisappear`, then reinstantiate it on `viewWillAppear` to reload the objects.

Comment: Thanks again. 
1)I have an app that uses UITabbarController. I use one VC for something that happens in longer time, i.e. saving GPS route. On other VC, I want to see current object(trip) as I create it. But if I didn't press "Save trip" I don't want to see it, although it's created in my MOC, but just not saved. I don't know whether you understand that saving context is not connected to creating object in my sceanrio.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah it does sound like you would need a separate context just for that (in probably a parent-child way so that the parent doesn't see it on the other VC until you have the child save) or to save the state in a different manner until you save it, at which point you then add the metadata to CoreData.

Comment: 2. Yeah, I save both contexts, otherwise, if only child would save it, data would never get to store.
3. Yeah, I saw it, great article, and yet, not giving me answers :(
4. I used parent as singleton, so all of other could see changes, but when I try to fetch again from same singleton parent, I never get changes, not from parent or store.